# Cross table of joint games

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I have a list of games of badminton that have been played over a period of time:

[image: available data]

Each row contains the game id and one player id. Each game was played with four players. So, for each game there are four rows (one for each player).
As we have many games, there are many duplicates in the list of players.

I wish to create a cross table that tells me how many times two players have been in a game together.

[image: desired table]

Can this be done with a formula? 
What would this formula be?

--- EDIT ---
To answer Scott's questions:

(1) Is a round the same as a game?

I made a mistake. Each round has multiple games; one on each available court. I should have said 'game' instead of 'round'. I have corrected this above.

(2) What’s the relationship between round X_1 and round X_2?

The number indicates the court that the game was played on. The example has two courts, in reality we have nine.

(3) Please show us the desired result, not just the format of the desired result.

I have replaced the image. By hand I have made the table for the example. ESK and GEN played together both games. YUG and PED both played just one game.
I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: (1) Is a round the same as a game?  If not, explain the difference. (2) What’s the relationship between round X_1 and round X_2? (3) Please show us the desired result, not just *the format of* the desired result. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### Grid Chart of *In Common Items* Count between Units
>
> Displays grid numbers for the count of Items two Units have in common.
>
> *Mutual Item Frequency chart.*

[[image: Sample]

> **The Grid Formula (CSE):**
>
> ```
> =IF(OR(E$2=$D3,E$2="",$D3=""),"",SUM(IFNA(MATCH(IF(E$2=$B$2:$B$102,$A$2:$A$102,NA()),IF($D3=$B$2:$B$102,$A$2:$A$102),0)^0,0)))
> ```

- Paste To: E3
- This is a CSE formula, so press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Copy Drag left, release then with all the copied cells still selected, copy drag down.
  Ok to drag beyond headers (fills with blanks until needed).
- Header Adjustments: Column heading row 2 `E$2` and Row heading column D `$D3`. Two occurrences each.
- Item & Unit ranges, $A$2:$A$102 and $B$2:$B$102, respectively.

> **Header Formulas:**
>
> Row **`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$17,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$2:D$2,$B$2:$B$17),0)),"")`**
>
> - Paste to  E2
>
> Column **`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$17,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$2:$D2,$B$2:$B$17),0)),"")`**
>
> - Paste to  D3

- Both are CSE so press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then copy drag as far as there may be future additional header items (displays blank after distinct values).
- Do Not put a value in **D2** that can appear in the Units Column.

  - D2 is the Expanding Ranges' ZERO position.
  - Both `$D$2:D$2` and `$D$2:$D2` are expanding ranges for the corresponding header's
    previous entries; used to create distinct header items.
- The header formulas are optional, but headers are not. Use care when entering manually.
- These headers are in order of first appearance. Use a `SMALL` distinct formula for sorted.

> **Conditional Formatting:**
>
> Diagonal Formula `=AND(E$2<>"",$D3=E$2)`
>     Applies to: `$E$3:$V$20` where **$V$20** is the bottom right of grid.
>   *Apply formatting fill or whatever.*

- Graded Color Scale (shown in image).
- List Diagonal Rule first. (The formula can been edited to show a Units Frequency on the diagonal.)
- Hide Zeros with this *Format Cell* custom format `#;;"";""` paint brush over grid.

> **Show the units' frequency on the diagonal:**

Remove the guard in the grid formula which shows *blank* `""` when the column and row header values are the same.

```
=IF(OR(E$2=$D3,E$2="",$D3=""),""...(see entire formula above)
.      ^^^^^^^^
```

- Delete `E$2=$D3,` from the grid formula (including the trailing comma).
- CSE after edit, and re- copy drag.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted and more!